# Java printing patterns

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm new in Java.
I have next code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int k = 10; k > 0; k--)
        {
            for(int l=0; l < k-1; l++)
                {
                    System.out.print(' ');
                }
            for(int n=10; n > k-1; n--)
                {
                    System.out.print('*');
                }
         System.out.println();
        } 
    }
```

It prints this:

```
         *
        **
       ***
      ****
     *****
    ******
   *******
  ********
 *********
**********
```

But I want to print it with empty inside like this:

```
         *
        **
       * *
      *  *
     *   *
    *    *
   *     *
  *      *
 *       *
**********
```

Can anyone to explane me how to do it.
I understand that this is not a place where solve homework tasks. But can somebody tell me the algorithm for solving the problem in words.
I do not need a ready solution because I want to understand and solve it by myself. So how I can put spaces inside?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: In the second loop you should print a `'*'` for the first and last values of `n`, not all of them.  For the other positions, print a `' '`.

Comment: and how to find first and last value?

Comment: Use an `if` statement.  And look at how you compute the values of `n`.

Answer (score -1):

Hint: in the second inner for loop, you could have an if statement where you check for n's greatest and lowest values, and k's lowest value, then print a '*', otherwise print a ' '. Like so:

```
for(int n = 10; n > k - 1; n--){
   if(n == 10 || n == k || k == 1){
     System.out.print('*');
   } else {
     System.out.print(' ');
   }
}
```